Populating values in the same sheet with two seperate tables
Is there a formula that updates a data table when constantly updated on another table?
I manually updated that table by just inserting a new row, copy pasting from previously completed row.
I want the table to be updated so i dont have to manually update the table itself.


This needs VBA. You cannot do this with formula.

if you're using actual named table ranges you could refer them to each other however and they'll update things like the amount. If you need another row you just begin typing beneath it and it will auto-add the row and the other table will automatically include that row in its formulas, but i'm not quite sure what you're trying to do how you posed the question. Your image doesn't add much clarity

Formulas cannot update a static range, you need to use VBA please edit the OP by posting your code what you have tried so that users can help you out!

If you meant 'inserting a new row' when you said 'update',
then unfortunately I don't think it's possible that can be
achieved with formula.
However, if you meant to change the value of cells accordingly, formula might work, depending on what exactly do you want to achieve.
